# Convert a dynamically linked elf binary to statically linked

Tags: c++, c, linux, elf

Is it possible to convert a dynamically linked elf binary to a statically linked one?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Tools which may help [Ermine](http://magicermine.com/), [Statifier](http://statifier.sourceforge.net/), and [jumpstart](http://bitwagon.com/jumpstart/jumpstart.html).

Comment: I had success with Ermine but not with Statifier. The first is propietary, the second is open-source. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is a solution to run statifier in systems that has address randomization:

You must disable the randomization before executing statifier, then re-enable it.

```
 [me@mypc ~]# cat /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
 2
 [me@mypc ~]# echo -n 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space    
 [me@mypc ~]# statify xxxxx yyyyyy
 .....
 [me@mypc ~]# echo -n 2 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
```

statifier.sh should be modified for automatically changing and restore this value if run as root, or to report the problem if not.

Comment: You also need to disable ASLR on the machine where you're running the binary.

Answer (score -2):

Not without recompiling (or at least relinking).